# Xcode fails linking regularly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am having a weird issue where regularly when i build and run i get this error

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed: 9
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Other times i get a dialog message that says `could not attach to simulator` or something like that.

I am not sure when this started, I have tried cleaning and removing the derived data.

The actual command that fails:

> Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.app/Company-dev normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/user/projects/Company/iOS
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireObjectMapper -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BDKCollectionIndexView -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DKImagePickerController -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookCore -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookLogin -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQKeyboardManagerSwift -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kingfisher -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mixpanel-swift -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapper -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmSwift -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simplicity -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SlideMenuControllerSwift -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKeychainWrapper -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftSpinner -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyUserDefaults -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Whisper -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/user/projects/Company/iOS/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Intermediates/Company.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Company-dev.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Intermediates/Company.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Company-dev_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Intermediates/Company.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Company_dev.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework ActionSheetPicker_3_0 -framework AddressBook -framework Alamofire -framework AlamofireObjectMapper -framework BDKCollectionIndexView -framework Bolts -framework Charts -framework Crashlytics -framework DKImagePickerController -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework Fabric -framework FacebookCore -framework FacebookLogin -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework IQKeyboardManagerSwift -framework Kingfisher -framework Mixpanel -framework ObjectMapper -framework Realm -framework RealmSwift -framework Security -framework Simplicity -framework SlideMenuControllerSwift -framework StoreKit -framework SwiftKeychainWrapper -framework SwiftSpinner -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SwiftyUserDefaults -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Whisper -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Intermediates/Company.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.build/Company-dev.app.xcent -framework Pods_Companyiabstract_Company_dev -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Intermediates/Company.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Company-dev_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Company-acovzggytrsxohabthueilablphe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Company-dev.app/Company-dev

Comment: Clean DerivedData folder and restart Xcode

Comment: And reset simulator

Comment: It seems to still be happening :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how I got it to work, but I found out which file regularly failed to be linked and the culprit was `SomeClass.o`. I tried moving the contents of the swift file,but that did not work, so I ended up refactoring the name of this class, and that did the trick.

It seems to me there was a cache somewhere which was not being deleted when derived data was deleted, I hope this helps someone else, because this bug was a bitch

Answer (score 0):

Clean Xcode Derived Data by:
`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`

Comment: Actually this did not work, I just got the error again